# Crop a image with square in front end

Tags: php, image, resize

I need a function that when the subscriber upload a image to my website they can crop  moving it a square the way they likes. But its also important to say that this image is pre-sized by a default size in the website, no matter what they crops with the square, the image size will be always: 130x130.

I use Wordpress, so if theres a code or plugin that you guys recomend me, its nice!

Thanks!

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_

Comment: Hi Andrei, check out https://www.imghaste.com (Disclaimer: I am the author) I can be of help integrating via Client Hints. and its free for small websites. though its indeed off-topic :)